# Не переносится текст в badge bootstrap 4

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap

Не переносится текст в badge на bootstrap 4. Смотрю под мобильной версией.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался.
Вдруг кому тоже понадобится.
В стилях к элементу пропишите

```
white-space: normal;
```